# How to back up Terraria game saves on Android?

Tags: android, terraria-mobile

Before updating to the new version (`1.1.6292`), I want to back-up the old game (the old version without hardmode - `1.04`) saves.

I can't seem to find them anywhere. How could this be? If the app has permissions to write them somewhere, I should be able to read/write on that location too, shouldn't I?

I'm afraid the new version will purge my old saves. If it's not possible to update them, I'd like to keep them for sentimental reasons...

Answer (score 1):

Your phone has to be rooted in order to reliably back up app data. I've used free [Oandbackup app](https://fossdroid.com/a/oandbackup.html), you can back up both `.apk` and app data.

Comment: Turns out for most useful things, a phone must be rooted.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea where they are saved, but you can try backing them up with [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en).

New versions generally don't purge saves, or even render them unplayable, just those worlds generated in previous versions won't have the features of the new version.

Comment: I don't have rooted phone. I used Ultimate backup Lite, but I'm not so sure it actually backs-up application data. I risked it however and my saves were not purged. Actually, both game versions are running separatelly including the world files. This is sad. I hoped to continue with my existing character.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out but it requires a computer. There is an app called [Helium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup&hl=en) for android, not so sure about iOS.

The app will download an installer to your phone - move it to your desktop (eg. over USB) and install it and follow the prompts on your android.

It will then ask you to turn on USB debugging, enable it. Then it will tell you to plug your device in to the computer, once you do that, it will enable you to back up the data and the `.apk` if you want to.

Follow the steps again on the device your switching your save over to, no need to re-download the file on your computer, it's not limited, it works on all android devices.

From there, on the device you want to play your saved world and character on. If you haven't already downloaded the game, do it and it will show a restore tab in the helium app. Plug your device in and if the computer shows a green check mark, restore it and there you go.

If you get an error, ignore it and proceed. I do not take any responsibility for ruined game data, but to assure you, it worked for me.